# How to make object of comma separated elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on a CSV parser, where I have data in array like

```
["Jonas", "Sched ", "jonas@sch.com", "ph:34988934", "data 1,data 2", "data 3,data 4", "data 5, data 6"]
```

What I want to achieve I want to make array of object of array element which contain comma (`,`).

Expected result:

```
 let array=  ["Jonas", "Sched ", "jonas@sch.com", "ph:34988934", items:[{name:data 1, temp:data
 2},{name:data 3, temp:data 4},{name:data 5, temp:data 6}]
```

Comment: Your expected output isn't valid syntactically. Did you mean e.g. `{name: "data 3", temp: "data 4"}`? Also what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Actually , I am parsing CSV data where I want to represent object data with comma separator like ( data1, data 2) . At final I will convert it into {name:data 1, temp: data 2 ) . I want to read this comma separator in string . could you please help me how to make object of from string which have comma separator like `"data1,data2"`

Comment: What part of that specifically do you have a problem with? Do you know how to check if a string has a (exactly one?) comma in? How to split on it? Be more specific, give a [mre] of what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is to pull things out of your original array. This can be done through a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const [name, company, email, phone, ...itemCsvs] = yourOriginalArray;
```

Notice the `...itemCsvs`; that destructures anything remaining after the first four items into an array with the variable name `itemCsvs`.

Each item in `itemCsvs` looks like comma-separated pairs. You can use the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) of those strings to convert them to string arrays:

```
const itemPairs = itemCsvs.map(str => str.split(','));
```

`itemPairs` is now an array of string arrays.

```
[
  ["data1", "data2"],
  ["data3", "data4"],
  ["data5", "data6"]  
]
```

Converting these into objects is then as simple as mapping again:

```
const items = itemPairs.map(([name, temp]) => ({ name, temp }));
```

Now you just reassemble the pieces. To put things together more compactly:

```js
const originalData = [
  "Jonas", "Sched ", "jonas@sch.com", "ph:34988934",
  "data 1,data 2", "data 3,data 4", "data 5, data 6"
];

const [name, company, email, phone, ...itemCsvs] = originalData;

const result = {
  name, company, email, phone,
  items: itemCsvs.map(item => {
    const [name, temp] = item.split(',');
    return { name, temp };
  })
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . What if we have multiple array like we discussed yesterday . I need to fit this example with multiple array

Comment: I want to use this same logic to make an array like `{dataItems:[{.........,items:[......] },{........,items:[] }  ]`. Could you please help me

Comment: Just run the same logic in an Array map like in the other question.