# Convert Array to object with custom keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have array which I want to convert to object . Like `['jonas','0302323','jonas84@gmail.com]`. Now what I want to achieve I want to convert array into object and I want to assign custom keys into that object .

Expected Result : `{name:'Jonas',phone:84394934,email:jonas84@gmail.com}`. I am beginner to JS could somone please help me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Destructuring makes this easy:

```js
const yourArray = ['Jimbo', '555-555-5555', 'jimbo@aol.com'];

const [name, phone, email] = yourArray;
const yourObject = { name, phone, email };

console.log(yourObject);
```

The first statement pulls items out of the array and assigns them to variables. The second statement creates a new Object with properties matching those variable names + values.

If you wanted to convert an Array of Arrays, simply use the same technique with `map`:

```js
const peopleArrays = [
  ['Jimbo', '555-555-5555', 'jimbo@aol.com'],
  ['Lakshmi', '123-456-7890', 'lakshmi@compuserve.com']
];

const peopleObjects = peopleArrays
  .map(([name, phone, email]) => ({ name, phone, email }));

console.log(peopleObjects);
```

Comment: what if we have multiple array case Like  [ [......],[..........] ]

Comment: Same concept. To convert an array of X to an array of Y, use its map function. Added an example.

Comment: one last thing please . In array I have string like  `[.... , .... , "data 1 , data 2 " ]` . what I want to achieve actually make an array of object like   [ ...... , ....... , items : [{name:data 1, phm:data2},......] Could you please help me

Comment: Sounds complicated, and it's not clear exactly what your input and output is. I'd suggest posting as a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582158/how-to-make-object-of-comma-separated-elements

Comment: Great job explaining this one. I was searching for a way to add keys to a preexisting array and this was the only solution I found shockingly. Great question and answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `Object.fromEntries` - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```
const keys = ['name', 'phone', 'email'];
const values = ['jonas','0302323','jonas84@gmail.com'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, index) => [key, values[index]]))
```