# Array of strings into object with label and id -> destructure error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've found similar but not understanding what is done wrong still. Am learning I know... I was trying to use technique [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583147/convert-array-to-object-with-custom-keys-in-javascript) but am not sure if it is right way and can not get it to work. I get `TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.`

I wish for array of string like; `['One', 'Two', 'Three']` to become object like below. Where I want to turn the array into an object with specific key that holds array of objects with those values as specific key/value object like below.

```
{
   items: [
      {
        label: 'One',
         id: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Two',
         id: 2
      },
      {
        label: 'Three',
         id: 3
      },
  ]
}
```

I try like

```css
let arrayOfStrings = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

const [label, id] = arrayOfStrings;

arrayOfStrings = [label, id];

document.write(arrayOfStrings);
```

Any guidance much appreciated!

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKyPpN), but it depends on your actual requirement.  How do we know that the id for `"One"` should be `1`?  Is it because you are starting with `1` and counting up (as opposed to a `0` index), or is it because the string `"One"` is an English word corresponding to the number `1`?  Or some other reason?  It would be helpful if you explicitly lay out your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope I got your question correctly
if your main goal is to turn something like this
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
into something like this
[
{
label: 'One',
id: 1
},
{
label: 'Two',
id: 2
},
{
label: 'Three',
id: 3
},
]
this should be fairly easy using the .map method on the array as so

```
 let arrayOfStrings = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
let newArrayOfString = arrayOfStrings.map((string,stringIndex)=>{return{label:string,id:stringIndex+1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```js
const input = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

const format = (array) => {
    const items = array.map((label, index) => ({label, id: index + 1}));
    return {items};
};

console.log(format(input));
```